# No stream() methods in quarkus 3

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

I would like to migrate my code from quarkus 2 to quarkus 3. All my code is reactive. I found some problems with stream() methods which were removed in quarkus 3.

Example code from quarkus 2. Fruit is an Entity which is stored in PG database.

`return Fruit.streamAll();`

How can I achieve the same result in quarkus 3? I prefer `Multi<Fruit>` than `Uni<List<Fruit>>`.

Comment: Please read [this commit's](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/29761/commits/99c4b70aa90788d0524337c7829221fe421c63e3) message to understand why it was removed

Comment: [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.0#support-of-multi) is the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
Multi<Fruit> fruits = Fruit.listAll()
  .onItem()
  .transformToMulti(list -> Multi.createForm().iterable(list));
```

Anyway I prefer quarkus 2 `Fruit.streamAll()` solution.